# VS Code give me this error: Unable to open 'Unknown Source': File not found (\Unknown Source)

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to run an ASP.NET Core application in VS Code, and I get this very unhelpful error:

> Unable to open 'Unknown Source': File not found (\Unknown Source).

It gives me the option to create the file (`C:\Unkown Source`), but then can't do that (not that I think it would help...).

Does anybody have any idea where to start with this one?

The project was created following [this guy's blog post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/05/02/angular2-react-knockout-apps-on-aspnet-core/). and it works fine on my other computer for some reason...

Comment: I just realized that if I do a "dotnet run" from the command line, it runs just fine... it's only when I try run the debugger that I get the error.

Comment: Do you have "C#" extension installed in vscode? Also, try to remove `.vscode` folder and reopen folder in vscode then

Comment: Hey Set, thanks for commenting. I do have the C# extension installed, and I deleted .vscode, but that didn't help unfortunately. Maybe I'll try re-install the C# extension.

Comment: Reinstalled the C# plugin.... it didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: Did you have an older VSCode version on your other computer? I think this might be a VSCode 1.9.0 regression: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/20622